# get access token from back and cache it to browser

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios, web-development-server

> hey guys. i'm working with **axios**,**nodeJS** and **vue** . i want
> to generate an ***accessToken*** in node (it's **done**) and get it
> with axios (it's **done** too) and cache it to browser cache with
> vue(**don't know** how), so whenever i want to send a request to
> node,i could send it with headers of axios , i dont know if it's
> possible or not ? need some help around here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible and is pretty common.
To do it, you just have to store the token in the browser memory (usually in the localStorage) and then use axios interceptors on the requests to automatically add the token.

How you can add items to local storage?

```
localStorage.setItem('my-key',my-value)
```

you can find the complete docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
   config => {

       //here retrieve the token and add it (if present)
       //most probably you would use VUEX for storing it 
       //in you app 
       const token = yourLocalStorageAccessor.getAccessToken();
       if (token) {
           config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
       }
       // config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
       return config;
   },
   error => {
       Promise.reject(error)
   });
```

You can read about axios interceptors **[here](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)**.